# pthreads extension loading fails in php-cli.ini

Tags: php, macos, pthreads

I have everything build and set, now I am trying to load pthreads extension but I am having this problem.

php scans for additional dir and finds

```
Additional .ini files parsed 
/Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini/php-cli.ini
```

Additionally

```
Additional .ini files parsed    /Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini/php-cli.ini, /Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini/php.ini
```

I added `extension=pthreads.so` in **php-cli.ini** file and `php -m` command lists the following modules:

```
Warning: Module 'pthreads' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
pcre
pthreads
Reflection
SPL
standard
```

Apache failed to start and When I remove or comment out `extension=pthreads.so` line,  `php -m` command lists the following modules:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
pcre
Reflection
SPL
standard
```

I tried renaming **php-cli.ini** to **cli.ini** and found something different....

php scans for additional dir and finds

```
Additional .ini files parsed 
/Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini/cli.ini
```

`php -m` command lists the following modules:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
pcre
pthreads
Reflection
SPL
standard
```

which is as expected but when restart apache , it fails to start and following is the error log

```
PHP Fatal error:  The apache2handler SAPI is not supported by pthreads in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pthreads module in Unknown on line 0
```

I don't have pthreads.so loaded in **php.ini**

**My environment** is Mac OSX 10.11, PHP 7.0.2, Apache 2.4.18

apache's mpm is worker,  I've enabled thread-safety of php and compiled pthreads as shared module.

What am I doing wrong, How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Check phpinfo() with apache to see what ini files are parsed.

Comment: Additional .ini files parsed    /Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini/php-cli.ini, /Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini/php.ini

Comment: You see, you php-cli.ini is parsed too, which cause pthreads to be loaded and screw apache start. Look into your php.ini to see why php-cli.ini is included.

Comment: how do I disable load of  php-cli.ini?  disable "scan of additional ini file" perhaps?

Comment: You can do that. Usually, in many Linux distribution you have separate files and folders for each SAPI. Since you're on Windows, I can't really guide you. Moreover, this setup has to be done as compile time ( with configure ). So ... you're screwed :D

Comment: You can of course refer to the doc to compile source by yourself : http://php.net/manual/fr/install.windows.building.php

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am on OSX  and I can built all tools from source :)

Comment: \o/ I misread that ! So yes you can. Compile each SAPI individually, specifying the correct option of --with-config-file-path=<pathToMainFile> --with-config-file-scan-dir=<pathToDirectoryWithAdditionalFiles>

Comment: For example, mines are :

--with-config-file-path=/etc/php/7.0/cli
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d

Comment: @JesusTheHun  Thanks !

Comment: None of that should be necessary. php-cli.ini should only be loaded by CLI ... it seems likely that you have your scan-dir set to Terminal/WebServer/ini ... config-file-path and config-file-scan-dir need to be set correctly at compile time ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pthreads extension is voluntary disabled in all SAPI but CLI. You cannot use pthreads with apache_mod nor php-fpm.